# SSD is not recognized after I took it out

Tags: boot, laptop, ssd

I took out the SSD from my laptop (ASUS UX31A) and reinstalled it.
(The Fedora operating system was installed on the SSD.)
After starting the laptop again the boot menu appears immediately.
The SSD is not listed there.
In the boot menu I already tried all settings, but nothing helped.

All I did was take out the SSD and put it back into the laptop.

Thereupon I started my laptop with a USB stick (Linux).
But here the SSD was listed and I could access all my folders without problems.

What can I do to make my laptop recognize the SSD again and boot from it?

Comment: Try again to take it out and put back in, while ensuring that the connections are solid.

Comment: I have already done this several times.

Comment: Maybe try to reset the BIOS to defaults.

Comment: Are you talking about the regular (UEFI) boot-menu where the SSD is missing or the special boot menu where all devices are listed even USB-sticks and so on? If it is the first then the UEFI entry may be just missing.

Comment: @harrymc I already did this.

Comment: @Robert I'm talking about the the second

Comment: Try another disk using the same connector, to see if it's listed.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately I don't have another SSD.

Comment: Any compatible hard disk will do.

Comment: The connection for the SSD is very special in my laptop. Therefore I have no other disc.